# Server side PHP page cache troubleshoot

Tags: php, caching, wordpress

I have been searching for further troubleshooting info on server side caching, however can only find info relating to using PHP to cache common elements.

I have a wordpress install, with WP_cache set to false. No CDN or Wordpress caching plugins.

I had an error in one .php file which was being called via the php include. The error was a missing / in the directory name with the PHP function move_uploaded_file() - In turn it was pointing to a non existing folder.

I have been developing on this server (OpenBSD, Apache 2.2, PHP 5.4) for a few weeks with no issues deleting and replacing php files, the new php pages would be processed instantly.

Now, the file with the error equipment.php is displaying the outputs of the .php page at the time of the error, I have replaced (and double checked server) and even deleted the page and it still shows the old php output.

I have a work around to change the includes to equipment2.php and rename the page - this worked.

The php logs show the error with the original function and also the missing equipment.php when I delete the file (despite php outputs being served). I have no access to php.ini to increase verbose. I am unable to restart Apache on the server.

I suspect the server is running some kind of caching or the PHP stored and serves an old version of the php page after certain errors.

Please assist with troublshooting for server side caching.

Comment: I've had similar issues with one server that stored all public files in a SAN. The problem was that it took a few hours to sync the file throughout the entire network. Have you checked if no such configuration exists on the server you're using?

Comment: @Diego I will look into this further, but it would not be consistent with other files in the same folder updating instantly. I have contacted the web server provider for further information as their control panel is very limited.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's caused by PHP's OPcache. Reload your PHP engine to clean the cache, or, if you don't have root access to the server, use this plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/opcache/

After activation, find your file on the plugin's page and delete it from cache.

Comment: Handy tool, I tried it out and the dashboard is blank so my server either isn't running OPcache or it's configuration doesn't match up with the plugin, I will however investigate further to see if OPcache is running.

Comment: Your total dashboard or just OPcache plugin's dashboard? I assumed you have OPcache as it's included in recent versions of PHP by default. But, if you have older version, you might have APC or XCache installed. Ask your hosting provider. When you know what's the caching engine it's easier to find a way to clean that cache.